# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfq

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I getting this error. Despite trying all thing I am unable to resolve it. Please help me.

Things that I tried are:

1. Delete `.build`, `.idea` etc then rebuild
2. Clean and rebuild
3. Change version of compile library

Thank you

plugins

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Android

```
android {
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.funzone.alarmnap"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.1"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
   }
```

Greendao Plugin

```
 apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
 greendao {
   targetGenDir 'src/main/java'
   schemaVersion 2
 }
```

All libraries:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0"
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.0'
}




repositories {
mavenCentral()
google()
}
```

Google plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I fix the same issue in my project - after updating the Kotlin plugin to 1.2.41 (I don't know if it is really related. ***Edit:*** apparently this is not related with Kotlin) - with :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

**Remark:** I could stay with the unique `15.0.0` Google Play Services libraries version but not the `play-services-tagmanager` one and `firebase` :

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
```

The project is compiling now.

Comment: You're right. There is a problem between "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0-15.0.1" and classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'. I just updated google-services to 3.2.1 and firebase to 15.0.2 and I can compile project now. Thanks! Note: I am not using Kotlin, so problem should be related with firebase-GooglePlayServices.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about the Kotlin related or not question!

Comment: Hello freinds, i am getting same error and i am using classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1', can anyone help me about this, i just update lettest firebase library like firebase database 17.0.4 to 17.1.2, please help me for this, thank you

Comment: Have you tried with the 4.1.0 or 4.2.0 version of the Google Services Gradle Plugin ? (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156783/8203894)

Answer (score 7):

1. set   `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'` at the app level `build.gradle` file, if you are using firebase
2. set `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` at the project level `build.gradle` file

Then sync the `build.gradle` files

Comment: Updating messaging was not sufficient for me. I ended up updating all my firebase implementations to the newest version. Notice that they have changed them to have independent [version numbers](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) now.

Answer (score 5):

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

and

```
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to update the version of the individual libraries. This addresses the issue where version 3.3.0 of the Google Services Gradle plugin reports: The library **com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base** is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0], [15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2...

[image]

For more info regarding the latest update check release updates from below link
[Firebase May 2nd release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: This helped me resolve a Xamarin Forms issue relating to Firebase Cloud Messaging. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I started seeing this after I upgraded to  kotlin plugin version : 1.2.41-release-Studio3.1-1.

Upgrading firebase-core and firebase-messaging from 15.0.0 --> 15.0.2. Fixed the problem, database, auth and gms-auth-services are at 15.0.0

Comment: when I'm trying to set firebase-core and firebase-messaging from 15.0.0 --> 15.0.2. and setting rest of the services like the database, auth, and gms-auth-services at 15.0.0 gives me below error.

`Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue using new firebase independent version numbers 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

> SDK Update - May 2, 2018 -> Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to add a quick summary of the link above just in case it goes offline. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I fixed it updating lines below:

**build.grade (Project: [project_name])**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

**build.grade (Module: app)**

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error. 
I was using

```
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

I solved it updating to

```
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

Another possible cause/fix might be the build.gradle at project level

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: did u find any solution for this

Comment: Dears please share if find any solution! I've tried many times and combinations: gradle plugin, gradle 4.4, 4.5, enable D8 multdex, disable... when I want debug... show: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn

Answer (score 1):

This is very boring. Google should review these updates better. I tried everything, but my issue was only fixed by returning the version of the Google Play Services APIs:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'`

Comment: I had this problem from nothing!! Why? Any idea?

Comment: Paulo, this is a very boring! In my project, i use firebase storage, auth, database. I don't "downgrade" to mount my project. Impossible. I've tried many types of configuration, include enable/disable D8 multdex..., update firebase APIs to newer 15.0.1 ... don't solve. A week ago, my project was perfect! Today crashed and I don't change anything! Really stop build! Incredible!!!

Comment: @Mateus Our team solved it by upgrading to the latest version of all Firebase & Play Services APIs (15.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot from firebase latest release notes]
Go to the folllowing link :
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android
and check for the latest firebase dependencies with the current compatible google play service version as shown in the screenshot below.

Comment: I updated         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' to         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'. And this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was

```
dependencies {
       classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
}
```

used for Performance Monitoring. Just commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the thing which is causing this error is 2 versions of same dependency with different services

I changed this: 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0' 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'

To: 
 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

these versions are importing same subpackages which is why it is a ambiguity error basically same subpackage is  imported from 2 different dependencies (in background)

Have fun coding!!