# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbn

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I tried all of the above suggestion in this [Forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599509/program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzfq/53361754#53361754) but I am still getting this error.

> Error: Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbn

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.14

Project Gradle ->

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // here
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

App Gradle ->

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'


   // Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4" // Analytics
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3" // Cloud Firestore
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5" // Authentication
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4" // Cloud Messaging / Notifications
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0" // Remote Config
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.3" // Invites / Dynamic Links
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0" // AdMob
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0" // Perf
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3" // Cloud Function

    // Location
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
```

gradle-wrapper.properties ->

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I was not able to fix this issue when I had reported it but now after updating the Firebase to the latest version, I am no longer getting this issue.